# Dir Restricted when using imagepng PHP GD

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, php-gd

I've one problem when upload my web to server. In localhost it works normally.

Basically my function is to update image with image and then store in new filename (image).

PHP Script :

```
        function updateimage()
    {


    //Try retriving data:
    $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
    $this->session->set_userdata("my_session_id", md5($ip));
    $ip = $this->session->userdata('my_session_id') ;




          $text1 = strtoupper ($this->input->post('text1'));
          $text2 = strtoupper ($this->input->post('text2'));
          $text3 = strtoupper ($this->input->post('text3'));


          $text1_align = $this->input->post('text1_align');
          $text2_align = $this->input->post('text2_align');
          $text3_align = $this->input->post('text3_align');



          $text1split = str_split($text1,1);
            $text2split = str_split($text2,1);
            $text3split = str_split($text3,1);            


          $image_tag = base_url().'images/tag.png';
          $image_A = base_url().'images/A.png';
          $image_B = base_url().'images/B.png';
          $image_C = base_url().'images/C.png';
          $image_D = base_url().'images/D.png';
          $image_E = base_url().'images/E.png';
          $image_F = base_url().'images/F.png';
          $image_G = base_url().'images/G.png';
          $image_H = base_url().'images/H.png';
          $image_I = base_url().'images/I.png';
          $image_J = base_url().'images/J.png';
          $image_K = base_url().'images/K.png';
          $image_L = base_url().'images/L.png';
          $image_M = base_url().'images/M.png';
          $image_N = base_url().'images/N.png';
          $image_O = base_url().'images/O.png';
          $image_P = base_url().'images/P.png';
          $image_Q = base_url().'images/Q.png';
          $image_R = base_url().'images/R.png';
          $image_S = base_url().'images/S.png';
          $image_T = base_url().'images/T.png';
          $image_U = base_url().'images/U.png';
          $image_V = base_url().'images/V.png';
          $image_W = base_url().'images/W.png';
          $image_X = base_url().'images/X.png';
          $image_Y = base_url().'images/Y.png';
          $image_Z = base_url().'images/Z.png';           

          $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($image_tag);


            imagealphablending($image_1, true);
            imagesavealpha($image_1, true);

            $text1len = (strlen($text1)*16)/2;
            $counter2 = (157 - ($text1len))+strlen($text1);

            if ($text1_align == 'on') $counter = 70; else $counter = $counter2;



        if ($text1split) {
            foreach ($text1split as $text1)
            {
             if ($text1 == 'A') {
                  $image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($image_A);
                imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
           }else if ($text1 == 'B'){ 
               $image_3 = imagecreatefrompng($image_B);
               imagecopy($image_1, $image_3, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
           }else if ($text1 == 'C') {
              $image_4 = imagecreatefrompng($image_C); 
           imagecopy($image_1, $image_4, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         } else if ($text1 == 'D') {
             $image_5 = imagecreatefrompng($image_D); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_5, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'E') {
             $image_6 = imagecreatefrompng($image_E); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_6, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'F') {
             $image_7 = imagecreatefrompng($image_F); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_7, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'G') {
             $image_8 = imagecreatefrompng($image_G); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_8, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'H')  {
             $image_9 = imagecreatefrompng($image_H); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_9, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
           }else if ($text1 == 'I') {
             $image_10 = imagecreatefrompng($image_I); 
              imagecopy($image_1, $image_10, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'J')  {
             $image_11 = imagecreatefrompng($image_J); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_11, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'K')  {
             $image_12 = imagecreatefrompng($image_K); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_12, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'L')  {
             $image_13 = imagecreatefrompng($image_L); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_13, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'M')  {
             $image_14 = imagecreatefrompng($image_M); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_14, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'N')  {
             $image_15 = imagecreatefrompng($image_N); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_15, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'O')  {
             $image_16 = imagecreatefrompng($image_O); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_16, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'P')  {
             $image_17 = imagecreatefrompng($image_P); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_17, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'Q')  {
             $image_18 = imagecreatefrompng($image_Q); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_18, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'R')  {
             $image_19 = imagecreatefrompng($image_R); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_19, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'S')  {
             $image_20 = imagecreatefrompng($image_S); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_20, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'T')  {
             $image_21 = imagecreatefrompng($image_T); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_21, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'U')  {
             $image_22 = imagecreatefrompng($image_U); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_22, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'V')  {
             $image_23 = imagecreatefrompng($image_V); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_23, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'W')  {
             $image_24 = imagecreatefrompng($image_W); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_24, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'X')  {
             $image_25 = imagecreatefrompng($image_X); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_25, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'Y')  {
             $image_26 = imagecreatefrompng($image_Y); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_26, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }else if ($text1 == 'Z')  {
             $image_27 = imagecreatefrompng($image_Z); 
             imagecopy($image_1, $image_27, $counter, 50, 0, 0, 16, 24);
         }  
             $counter = $counter+16;    
           }    
       }



            $text2len = (strlen($text2)*16)/2;
            $counter2 = (157 - ($text2len))+strlen($text2);

            if ($text2_align == 'on') $counter = 70; else $counter = $counter2;

          if ($text2split) { 
            foreach ($text2split as $text1)
            {
             if ($text1 == 'A') imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'B') imagecopy($image_1, $image_3, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'C') imagecopy($image_1, $image_4, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'D') imagecopy($image_1, $image_5, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'E') imagecopy($image_1, $image_6, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'F') imagecopy($image_1, $image_7, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'G') imagecopy($image_1, $image_8, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'H') imagecopy($image_1, $image_9, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'I') imagecopy($image_1, $image_10, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'J') imagecopy($image_1, $image_11, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'K') imagecopy($image_1, $image_12, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'L') imagecopy($image_1, $image_13, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'M') imagecopy($image_1, $image_14, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'N') imagecopy($image_1, $image_15, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'O') imagecopy($image_1, $image_16, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'P') imagecopy($image_1, $image_17, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Q') imagecopy($image_1, $image_18, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'R') imagecopy($image_1, $image_19, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'S') imagecopy($image_1, $image_20, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'T') imagecopy($image_1, $image_21, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'U') imagecopy($image_1, $image_22, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'V') imagecopy($image_1, $image_23, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'W') imagecopy($image_1, $image_24, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'X') imagecopy($image_1, $image_25, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Y') imagecopy($image_1, $image_26, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Z') imagecopy($image_1, $image_27, $counter, 75, 0, 0, 16, 24);

             $counter = $counter+16;    
           }    
        }


            $text3len = (strlen($text3)*16)/2;
            $counter2 = (157 - ($text3len))+strlen($text3);

            if ($text3_align == 'on') $counter = 70; else $counter = $counter2;

          if ($text3split) { 
            foreach ($text3split as $text1)
            {
             if ($text1 == 'A') imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'B') imagecopy($image_1, $image_3, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'C') imagecopy($image_1, $image_4, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'D') imagecopy($image_1, $image_5, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'E') imagecopy($image_1, $image_6, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'F') imagecopy($image_1, $image_7, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'G') imagecopy($image_1, $image_8, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'H') imagecopy($image_1, $image_9, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'I') imagecopy($image_1, $image_10, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'J') imagecopy($image_1, $image_11, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'K') imagecopy($image_1, $image_12, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'L') imagecopy($image_1, $image_13, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'M') imagecopy($image_1, $image_14, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'N') imagecopy($image_1, $image_15, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'O') imagecopy($image_1, $image_16, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'P') imagecopy($image_1, $image_17, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Q') imagecopy($image_1, $image_18, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'R') imagecopy($image_1, $image_19, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'S') imagecopy($image_1, $image_20, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'T') imagecopy($image_1, $image_21, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'U') imagecopy($image_1, $image_22, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'V') imagecopy($image_1, $image_23, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'W') imagecopy($image_1, $image_24, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'X') imagecopy($image_1, $image_25, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Y') imagecopy($image_1, $image_26, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);
             else if ($text1 == 'Z') imagecopy($image_1, $image_27, $counter, 100, 0, 0, 16, 24);

             $counter = $counter+16;    
           }    
        }

                $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\simtag\images/".$ip."tag2.png";

echo "Dir: " . dirname($path) . "<br />"; 
echo "File: " . $path . "<br />"; 

$seperator = '<br>';// and this 

echo ( is_writable(dirname($path))?'DIR writeable':'dir Restricted' ) .  $seperator; 
if( ! file_exists($path) ) 
  die('File does not exist'); 

echo is_writable($path)?'File writeable':'File has insufficient perms'; 
die(); 

            $this->save_imagepng($image_1,$path); 
            //imagepng($image_1, $path);
                 imagedestroy($image_1);

            redirect('home');

    }

function save_imagepng($img,$fname)
{
  ob_start();// store output
  imagepng($img);// output to buffer
  file_put_contents($fname, ob_get_contents(), FILE_BINARY);// write buffer to file
  ob_end_clean();// clear and turn off buffer 
}
```

When running its nothing happened , then  I check folder writable or not it comes like this

```
Dir: /home/kagasiac/public_html\simtag\images
File: /home/kagasiac/public_html\simtag\images/44801aed40d934e6b15c89a2363cc9abtag2.png
dir Restricted
File does not exist
```

Any idea?

Comment: Off-topic, but I'll bet you'd be interested to know about [switch in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Instead of using DOCUMENT_ROOT you may need to specify the file structure starting from public_html. You're web server may not allow a reference to DOCUMENT_ROOT directory. Also, you have mixed up \ and / in the file path. \ is an escape character so you might have to specify it twice \\simtag\\images

Comment: thank you @brett i change to $path = "\\public_html\\simtag\\images\\".$ip."tag2.png"; but the file saved in root folder with name \public_html\simtag\images\8973ee1cd414efaff7d0e71b138609a0tag2.png not in folder images.

Comment: @reefman and that worked?

Comment: not yet because image file not saved in right folder :(

Comment: @reefman can yo tell me where it saved the file?

Comment: in public_html/simtag with name \public_html\simtag\images\8973ee1cd414efaff7d0e71b138609a0tag2.png not in public_html/simtag/images

Comment: @reefman ok instead of \\ just use /

Comment: works like a charm! thank you @breet!! :)

Comment: On a side note, anytime you have this kind of duplication, it is a sign that you need to figure out a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just so people don't have to read through the comments on the question. The solution was to change the base directory to start at public_html and use /

So for this example

```
$path = "/public_html/simtag/images/".$ip."tag2.png";
```

instead of

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\simtag\images/".$ip."tag2.png";
```

This is often due to restrictions by the server. Can't access base directories in shared hosting.